# Generators of free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Ive been reading an introduction on free groups and have come across some difficulty

if i have the free group $\mathbb{Z*Z}$ , then what would the generators of this group be?

i am confused as examples i have seen of free group generators tend to be finite where as $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite.

any help on this would be great

Comment: What do you mean by "finite generators"? Perhaps you meant "finite **set** of (free) generators"? This is true if the free group's rank is finite, of course.

Comment: Generators of the free product $\;\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z\;$ are $\;1_L,1_R\;$, distinguishing between left and right elements.

Comment: $\langle\Bbb Z, +\rangle$ is an infinite group, but it is  still generated by the element $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: This group is presented as $\langle g_1,g_2\ |\qquad\rangle$, i.e. a group in two generators, $g_1,g_2$ and with no relations between them.